# MongoDB docker build failing due to Fatal Assertion 28558 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_util.cpp 365

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose

I have a docker-file that starts up a MongoDB instance. I a docker-compose file to bring up this container.

Here is what the docker-compose.yml file looks like:

```
version: "2"
services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    build: ./mongo
    volumes:
      - /my_data/mongo:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
      - "28017:28017"
```

This works great! If I run it, it will bring up Mongo and the container is live. However, I have a cifs share that I mounted to my machine as a volume, and I would like my Mongo to write data to this share rather than /my_data folder on my VM.

I did the following:

```
version: "2"
services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    build: ./mongo
    volumes:
      - /my_volume/mongo:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
      - "28017:28017"
```

There does not appear to be a permissions issue, and Docker tries to use this directory and creates a mongo.lock file inside the volume. However, docker-compose fails to bring up my container, and when I do docker-compose logs mongo, I get the following back trace:

```
2019-06-20T16:32:10.821+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=5 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=7e617ebf21ca
2019-06-20T16:32:10.822+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.21
2019-06-20T16:32:10.822+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: ba2e818de44c9a331ce09a624780a2bd841cf6e4
2019-06-20T16:32:10.822+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2019-06-20T16:32:10.822+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2019-06-20T16:32:10.822+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-06-20T16:32:10.822+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-06-20T16:32:10.822+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2019-06-20T16:32:10.822+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-06-20T16:32:10.822+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-06-20T16:32:10.822+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "0.0.0.0", http: { RESTInterfaceEnabled: true, enabled: true } } }
2019-06-20T16:32:10.841+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=3479M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2019-06-20T16:32:10.868+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (22) [1561048330:868110][5:0x7f8efa36bd40], connection: /data/db/: directory-sync: fdatasync: Invalid argument
2019-06-20T16:32:10.868+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31804) [1561048330:868258][5:0x7f8efa36bd40], connection: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
2019-06-20T16:32:10.868+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28558 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_util.cpp 365
2019-06-20T16:32:10.868+0000 I -        [initandlisten]

***aborting after fassert() failure


2019-06-20T16:32:10.894+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).

 0x559dd6fc2861 0x559dd6fc1a79 0x559dd6fc1f5d 0x7f8ef8f6a390 0x7f8ef8bc4428 0x7f8ef8bc602a 0x559dd6256ba5 0x559dd6cc67b6 0x559dd6261222 0x559dd6261447 0x559dd62616a9 0x559dd7976477 0x559dd7976612 0x559dd7976f9b 0x559dd79731a1 0x559dd78d19e6 0x559dd799368f 0x559dd797104b 0x559dd791fcba 0x559dd6caabdf 0x559dd6ca32d2 0x559dd6b95f00 0x559dd6242fa3 0x559dd6262a56 0x7f8ef8baf830 0x559dd62c2c09
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"559DD5A16000","o":"15AC861","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"559DD5A16000","o":"15ABA79"},{"b":"559DD5A16000","o":"15ABF5D"},{"b":"7F8EF8F59000","o":"11390"},{"b":"7F8EF8B8F000","o":"35428","s":"gsignal"},{"b":"7F8EF8B8F000","o":"3702A","s":"abort"},{"b":"559DD5A16000","o":"840BA5","s":"_ZN5mongo32fassertFailedNoTraceWithLocationEiPKcj"},{"b":"559DD5A16000","o":"12B07B6"},{"b":"559DD5A16000","o":"84B222","s":"__wt_eventv"},{"b":"559DD5A16000","o":"84B447","s":"__wt_err"},{"b":"559DD5A16000","o":"84B6A9","s":"__wt_panic"},{"b":"559DD5A16000","o":"1F60477"},{"b":"559DD5A16000","o":"1F60612"},{"b":"559DD5A16000","o":"1F60F9B"},{"b":"559DD5A16000","o":"1F5D1A1","s":"__wt_open"},{"b":"559DD5A16000","o":"1EBB9E6","s":"__wt_block_manager_create"},{"b":"559DD5A16000","o":"1F7D68F","s":"__wt_schema_create"},{"b":"559DD5A16000","o":"1F5B04B","s":"__wt_turtle_init"},{"b":"559DD5A16000","o":"1F09CBA","s":"wiredtiger_open"},{"b":"559DD5A16000","o":"1294BDF","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_PNS_11ClockSourceES8_mbbbb"},{"b":"559DD5A16000","o":"128D2D2"},{"b":"559DD5A16000","o":"117FF00","s":"_ZN5mongo20ServiceContextMongoD29initializeGlobalStorageEngineEv"},{"b":"559DD5A16000","o":"82CFA3"},{"b":"559DD5A16000","o":"84CA56","s":"main"},{"b":"7F8EF8B8F000","o":"20830","s":"__libc_start_main"},{"b":"559DD5A16000","o":"8ACC09","s":"_start"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.4.21", "gitVersion" : "ba2e818de44c9a331ce09a624780a2bd841cf6e4", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "4.4.0-96-generic", "version" : "#119-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 12 14:59:54 UTC 2017", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "b" : "559DD5A16000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C0CF6DEDE77121E69C05F8DAB8835E6C51B3261E" }, { "b" : "7FFCB15AD000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "0A63E8ED537104D9ABE07E9C9B77F8B49052BF37" }, { "b" : "7F8EF9EE6000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "FF69EA60EBE05F2DD689D2B26FC85A73E5FBC3A0" }, { "b" : "7F8EF9AA1000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "15FFEB43278726B025F020862BF51302822A40EC" }, { "b" : "7F8EF9899000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "69143E8B39040C964D3958490535322675F15DD3" }, { "b" : "7F8EF9695000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "37BFC3D8F7E3B022DAC7943B1A5FACD40CEBF0AD" }, { "b" : "7F8EF938C000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "BAD67A84E56E73D031AE507261DA066B35949D34" }, { "b" : "7F8EF9176000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "68220AE2C65D65C1B6AAA12FA6765A6EC2F5F434" }, { "b" : "7F8EF8F59000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B17C21299099640A6D863E423D99265824E7BB16" }, { "b" : "7F8EF8B8F000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1CA54A6E0D76188105B12E49FE6B8019BF08803A" }, { "b" : "7F8EFA14F000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C0ADBAD6F9A33944F2B3567C078EC472A1DAE98E" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x41) [0x559dd6fc2861]
 mongod(+0x15ABA79) [0x559dd6fc1a79]
 mongod(+0x15ABF5D) [0x559dd6fc1f5d]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x11390) [0x7f8ef8f6a390]
 libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38) [0x7f8ef8bc4428]
 libc.so.6(abort+0x16A) [0x7f8ef8bc602a]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo32fassertFailedNoTraceWithLocationEiPKcj+0x0) [0x559dd6256ba5]
 mongod(+0x12B07B6) [0x559dd6cc67b6]
 mongod(__wt_eventv+0x3D7) [0x559dd6261222]
 mongod(__wt_err+0x9D) [0x559dd6261447]
 mongod(__wt_panic+0x2E) [0x559dd62616a9]
 mongod(+0x1F60477) [0x559dd7976477]
 mongod(+0x1F60612) [0x559dd7976612]
 mongod(+0x1F60F9B) [0x559dd7976f9b]
 mongod(__wt_open+0x491) [0x559dd79731a1]
 mongod(__wt_block_manager_create+0x66) [0x559dd78d19e6]
 mongod(__wt_schema_create+0x4EF) [0x559dd799368f]
 mongod(__wt_turtle_init+0x36B) [0x559dd797104b]
 mongod(wiredtiger_open+0x194A) [0x559dd791fcba]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_PNS_11ClockSourceES8_mbbbb+0x70F) [0x559dd6caabdf]
 mongod(+0x128D2D2) [0x559dd6ca32d2]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo20ServiceContextMongoD29initializeGlobalStorageEngineEv+0x6B0) [0x559dd6b95f00]
 mongod(+0x82CFA3) [0x559dd6242fa3]
 mongod(main+0x966) [0x559dd6262a56]
 libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xF0) [0x7f8ef8baf830]
 mongod(_start+0x29) [0x559dd62c2c09]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
```

Does anyone know how to address this error?

Comment: Any sugestion about this ERROR ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The important error message here is `/data/db/: directory-sync: fdatasync: Invalid argument`. This means that the filesystem doesn't support `fsync()` on directories. This is required by MongoDB, as per the [Production Notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#fsync-on-directories):

> MongoDB requires a filesystem that supports fsync() on directories. For example, HGFS and Virtual Box’s shared folders do not support this operation.

Comment: I don't think this is the case, I am seeing it as well on system where it previously worked

Comment: @ZdenekMachek I'm not sure I understand. The answer helped the OP because it was directed to their specific question. If it doesn't work for you, then obviously your situation is different and you should post your own question.

Comment: I don't believe answer is solution for the problem and also it has nothing to do with programming ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try running a repair on the mongo db container. It should repair your database and the error related to WiredTiger should be fixed.

Start mongo container in bash mode.

```
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run mongo bash

or

docker run -it mongo bash
```

Once you are inside the docker container, run mongo db repair.

```
mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair
```

The DB should repaired successfully and all your data should be restored.

Note that you may also need to upgrade the version of mongodb ensuring the compatibility of the database files.